# How to perform a Chargent partial refund in apex

Tags: chargent

Does anyone have an example of how to perform a partial refund using Chargent?  We have successfully used authorize, charge, and refund (full refund), but cannot find an example of how to perform a partial refund using apex code.

Thanks.

Comment: What did Chargent support say?

Comment: They said we would have to buy a higher tier of support to get an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Partial refund via the UI is supported as part of your subscription.

Let me clarify a statement in your question, you do not need a higher tier of support as everyone gets the same level of support, you need to be on a higher tier edition of the product which includes API access.

In order to perform a partial refund via apex you will need to be on the Platform Edition where API access is enabled or purchase al carte API access.

Once you have purchased the above access you will be provided with instructions on how to do this and their support will assist you with questions if needed.

*Disclaimer* I am affiliated with Appfrotier